# Partial differential equations $u u_{xy} + u_{x} = y$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am self studying partial differential equations and I can do every problem in the first chapter except for this one.  Can anyone help me?

> Solve this partial differential equation.
>
> $u u_{xy} + u_{x} = y$

Comment: What is the chapter about? What methods?

Comment: It is literally called "Introduction", and they introduced various different PDEs.  For example, we have this PDE, $$u_{xx}-u_{yy} = 0$$ and the functions $u(x,y) = (x+y)^3$ and $u(x,y) = sin(x-y)$ are solutions of that equation.

They also talked about homogeneous and nonhomogeneous  PDEs.

Comment: I think it is a difficult problem for a first chapter. Have you learned Charpet method?

Comment: The Charpit's method is in chapter 4, so I haven't look at it yet.

Comment: I you dont mind may I ask which book are you followin?

Comment: It is the "Linear Partial
Differential Equations
for Scientists and Engineers" by Tyn Myint-U
Lokenath Debnath

Comment: I look at that book. That equation is given as an example of a PDE at the very beginning  without mentioning any of its solution.  It is not possible to solve every equation even  linear one. That's why It seemed tome difficult. However, it can be reduced to a first order nonlinear PDE: $\big (\frac{1}{2}u_y^2+u\big)_x= y\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}u_y^2+u= xy+f(y)$, where $f$ is arbitrary function. The Charpit's method is used to solve this type of equations.

Comment: @daulomb Not the same PDE: yours has $u_y u_{xy}$ on the left, not $uu_{xy}$.

Comment: right :)  so you see it is also not easy to reduce

Answer (score 2):

Upon inspection: the book does not say "Solve this partial differential equation". It says "Look, this is a partial differential equation." You are supposed to look at it and say "Yes, I see, this is a partial differential equation." Nobody expects you to solve it, and you should not expect that there is a formula for its solutions.

[image]

Having a formula for solutions of a PDE (or even of an ODE) is an exception, not a rule. Textbooks present as exercises only carefully designed equations for which the methods they present work. If you compose a PDE at random by multiplying and adding a bunch of derivatives, none of those methods will yield a solution.

Comment: Oh ok thank you! I was trying to solve this for like two days and couldn't find a solution!

Comment: +1 your commentary makes me laugh. "Yes, I see, this is a partial differential equation."